# "Wiremock invalid response: 3"

Tags: spring-boot, testing, wiremock, mockmvc

I'm trying use `wiremock` to simulate api result and test my endpoint. But unfortunately, I got response from exception `"I/O error on GET request for "http://localhost:56994": Invalid response: 3".`

1. I'm setting `wiremock` (it seems to work correctly (all logs working - start-stop)

```
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class WeatherControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @RegisterExtension
    public static WireMockExtension wireMockServer = WireMockExtension.newInstance()
            .options(wireMockConfig().dynamicPort())
            .build();

    @DynamicPropertySource
    public static void propertyOverride(DynamicPropertyRegistry registry) {
        registry.add("api.weather.cityNames", () -> "Jastarnia");
        registry.add("api.weather.apiKey", () -> "123");
        registry.add("api.weather.baseUrl", wireMockServer::baseUrl);
    }
```

2. Now I want to fake my API response by using wiremock

```
        //given
        FetchWeatherResponse fetchWeatherResponse = new FetchWeatherResponse(
                "Jastarnia",
                Arrays.asList(
                        new FetchWeatherResponse.WeatherData(20.5, 10.2, "2024-01-05"),
                        new FetchWeatherResponse.WeatherData(18.9, 8.6, "2024-01-06")
                )
        );
        String json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(fetchWeatherResponse);
        wireMockServer.stubFor(WireMock.get(WireMock.urlPathEqualTo("/"))
                .withQueryParam("city", WireMock.equalTo("Jastarnia"))
                .withQueryParam("key", WireMock.equalTo("123"))
                .willReturn(aResponse()
                        .withStatus(OK)
                        .withHeader("Content-Type", APPLICATION_JSON)
                        .withBody(json)));
```

I tried with that body or with

```
                        .withBody("""
                            {
                            "city_name": "Warsaw",
                                "data": [
                                    {
                                        "temp": 20.5,
                                            "wind_spd": 10.2,
                                            "datetime": "2024-01-05"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "temp": 18.9,
                                            "wind_spd": 8.6,
                                            "datetime": "2024-01-06"
                                    }
                                ]
                            }""".trim())));
```

- result is this same as above

Application works correctly but thats my impl

```
    @Override
    public List<FetchWeatherResponse> fetchWeather(List<String> urls) {
        final HttpEntity<HttpHeaders> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(createHeader());
        List<FetchWeatherResponse> fetchedWeathers = new LinkedList<>();
        try {
            for (String uri : urls) {
                FetchWeatherResponse fetchedWeather = makeWeatherRequest(requestEntity, uri);
                if(fetchedWeather == null) {
                    log.error("Response body was null.");
                    throw new ResponseStatusException(NO_CONTENT);
                }
                fetchedWeathers.add(fetchedWeather);
            }
            return fetchedWeathers;
        } catch (ResourceAccessException e) {
            log.error("Error while fetching locations: " + e.getMessage());
            throw new ResponseStatusException(INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }

    private FetchWeatherResponse makeWeatherRequest(HttpEntity<HttpHeaders> requestEntity, String url) {
        ResponseEntity<FetchWeatherResponse> response = restTemplate.exchange(
                url,
                GET,
                requestEntity,
                new ParameterizedTypeReference<>() {
                });
        log.info("data downloaded successfully");
        return response.getBody();
    }
```

it throws `throw new ResponseStatusException(INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);`.
before         log.info("data downloaded successfully");
so there is 100% error while fetching data.

```
thats my ResponseObject
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class FetchWeatherResponse {
    @JsonProperty("city_name")
    String cityName;
    @JsonProperty("data")
    List<WeatherData> data;

    @Data
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @NoArgsConstructor
    public static class WeatherData {
        @JsonProperty("temp")
        double temperature;
        @JsonProperty("wind_spd")
        private double windSpd;
        @JsonProperty("datetime")
        private String datetime;
    }
}
```

```
        MvcResult response = mockMvc.perform(get("/api/best-weather?date=2024-01-05")
                .contentType(APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andReturn();
```

```
And thats my full logs of wiremock during request

p.b.w.domain.weather.WeatherServiceImpl  : generated url http://localhost:57135?city=Jastarnia&key=123
2024-01-06T00:28:25.285+01:00 ERROR 16300 --- [           main] p.b.w.i.fetch.FetchWeatherImpl           : Error while fetching locations: I/O error on GET request for "http://localhost:57135": Invalid response: 3

MockHttpServletRequest:
      HTTP Method = GET
      Request URI = /api/best-weather
       Parameters = {date=[2024-01-05]}
          Headers = [Content-Type:"application/json;charset=UTF-8"]
             Body = null
    Session Attrs = {}

Handler:
             Type = pl.bartoszmech.weather.application.controller.WeatherController
           Method = pl.bartoszmech.weather.application.controller.WeatherController#getWeather(String)

Async:
    Async started = false
     Async result = null

Resolved Exception:
             Type = org.springframework.web.server.ResponseStatusException

ModelAndView:
        View name = null
             View = null
            Model = null

FlashMap:
       Attributes = null

MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 503
    Error message = null
          Headers = [Content-Type:"application/json"]
     Content type = application/json
             Body = {"message":"500 INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR"}
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []

java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<200> but was:<503>
Expected :200
Actual   :503
```

If you have question just ask.

I tried with different body responses, without queryParams (implementing it manually inside url)

Answer (score 0):

Your returned status OK from response is from:

```
import static javax.security.auth.callback.ConfirmationCallback.OK;
```

and it's hardcoded to 3, which is not valid http status code.
Instead use for example `HttpStatus.OK.value()`.
Unfortunately rest template give you error message that is not very clear.
When you change rest template for WebClient you would get error like this:
org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientRequestException: Status code '3' should be a three-digit positive integer.